# TornadoFX (JavaFX):How to perform action when view becomes visible

Tags: kotlin, javafx, tornadofx

I'm new to TornadoFX and I'm having trouble detecting if a view is visible or not
My scenario is:
I have views with custom menu items, I have already added the framework to ensure these are all added to my main menubar.
What I want to do now is make these visible/invisible if the given view is visible to the user.
My views are (in this instance) part of tabs in a tab pane. similar to...

```
root = tabpane {
  tab {
    content = MyView.root
...
```

I have tried

```
root.focusedProperty().onChange { state -> menu.isVisible = state }
```

This works when I click on the view (a list view in this case) but this view is not automatically focussed when I select the tab.
I have also tried

```
root.visibleProperty().onChange { state -> menu.isVisible = state }
```

but this property does not change when the view is "Shown" by selecting the tab (I assume this property is only set if I manually show/hide the view)

I could move the logic up to the tab itself but this breaks encapsulation.
The view should not have to know that it's part of a tab and the tab should not have to know that part of its content tree require triggering

Is there a property I can use (or another mechanism) to detect if the user can see the view
i.e. if the view is upper most within the application?

As a separate question, is this the right approach or is there a built in way of achieving the dynamic menus? - This is something I took for granted in .net WPF

Comment: Why would you care about that? The view should render itself whenever it is marked as visible by the framework.

Comment: "Visible" is not the correct property to be thinking about here; it probably doesn't quite mean what you think it should mean. With a tab pane, you have the notion of selection, so if you "moved the logic up to the tab pane", I assume you would do something like register a listener with the tab pane's selection model. To keep the encapsulation I think you are looking for, you could create your own property (in Java `Property<Node> selectedView = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();`) and register a listener with it. Then for a tab pane, simply update that property when the selection changes.

Comment: No idea what you mean by "dynamic menus" here, btw.

Comment: Thanks Jame, I'll try that
BTW - By dynamic menus I mean adding/removing menu items that are relevant to the displayed view - e.g. Add customer when (and only when) the CustomerView is displayed,
This functionality is available in .net (as if I remember correctly, also in c++ MFC with Document/View apps)

Comment: @Taoist The menu items are stored as a [list](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html), so all the regular list operations will work. I.e. `myMenu.getItems().add(...);`, `myMenu.getItems().remove(...)`. If you want to rebuild the entire menu from scratch, you can do `myMenu.getItems().setAll(...)`.